# Security risk of showing user's HTML content on a page that only he can access

Tags: html, xss

I have a textarea wherein the user can enter any kind of HTML (and that includes javascript). After that, I allow the user to preview it in his browser. The way that works is by POSTing the content to a page that displays the said content in a "template" kind of thing. The backend's in PHP.

**Page 1**

```
an HTML form that simply has a textarea
```

**Page 2 (where the form gets submitted)**

```
PHP code to echo the HTML entered in the textarea unmodified,
with an intention of keeping all HTML formatting as-is
```

Now, I'm aware of XSS. But my intention here is to only allow that particular user to preview whatever he's written. The content he enters won't be stored or shown to other people.

Since I'll be allowing anonymous users, my idea was to use a simple CSRF-like protection to ensure that only the user who generated the preview can view it.

That's the basic idea. I want the user to be able to preview arbitrary HTML of his choosing, while not opening up potential security holes. Is there any security aspect I'm overlooking?

Comment: Are you going to use something like **showdown** to preview? If not, what previewing engine are you gonna use?

Comment: In simplicity, I'll just be echoing the user contents back, but with some additional markup. So my templating engine is just a strategically placed "php echo statement."

Comment: So dude, it is not javascript, but using PHP right?

Comment: Yes, it is PHP. In concept, you enter some HTML, and the PHP script simply echoes it back to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that in your code, there is an AJAX call submitting the content and it gets converted and comes out. So, in your PHP file, while outputting the code, give this.

#### Method #1: HTML Safe

```
<?php
    ...
    $output = /* The final output */;
    $output = htmlspecialchars($output);
    die ($output);
?>
```

#### Method #2: Stripping certain tags

```
<?php
    ...
    $output = /* The final output */;
    $aDisabledAttributes = array('onabort', 'onactivate', 'onafterprint', 'onafterupdate', 'onbeforeactivate', 'onbeforecopy', 'onbeforecut', 'onbeforedeactivate', 'onbeforeeditfocus', 'onbeforepaste', 'onbeforeprint', 'onbeforeunload', 'onbeforeupdate', 'onblur', 'onbounce', 'oncellchange', 'onchange', 'onclick', 'oncontextmenu', 'oncontrolselect', 'oncopy', 'oncut', 'ondataavaible', 'ondatasetchanged', 'ondatasetcomplete', 'ondblclick', 'ondeactivate', 'ondrag', 'ondragdrop', 'ondragend', 'ondragenter', 'ondragleave', 'ondragover', 'ondragstart', 'ondrop', 'onerror', 'onerrorupdate', 'onfilterupdate', 'onfinish', 'onfocus', 'onfocusin', 'onfocusout', 'onhelp', 'onkeydown', 'onkeypress', 'onkeyup', 'onlayoutcomplete', 'onload', 'onlosecapture', 'onmousedown', 'onmouseenter', 'onmouseleave', 'onmousemove', 'onmoveout', 'onmouseover', 'onmouseup', 'onmousewheel', 'onmove', 'onmoveend', 'onmovestart', 'onpaste', 'onpropertychange', 'onreadystatechange', 'onreset', 'onresize', 'onresizeend', 'onresizestart', 'onrowexit', 'onrowsdelete', 'onrowsinserted', 'onscroll', 'onselect', 'onselectionchange', 'onselectstart', 'onstart', 'onstop', 'onsubmit', 'onunload')
    $output = strip_tags($output, "<p><a><b><i><em><strong><table><ul><ol><li>");
    die ($output);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Pravin. I've updated the question for clarity. I don't want to strip any of the HTML tags. I just want to know if printing the actual HTML content as-is is safe.

Comment: Other than client side scripts, he cannot access your server. It is very safer than you think! :)